# mongodb for django

Tags: django, mongodb

I like mongodb and django,and there are some frameworks to select:

- mongodbengine
- django-mongodb-engine

Mongodbengine has good performance and django ORM like api,but when serialize ,it's not supported now.

Django-mongodb-engine is a django backend,you can use it with django ORM.

So django-mongodb-engine is better? and how about its performance?

Comment: this thread should be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972480/has-anybody-actually-used-django-mongodb/9306519#9306519

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of projects out there for incorporating MongoDB with Django but the best one (I believe) is yet to come. Alex Gaynor's Google Summer of Code project is working on a queryset refactor of the Django ORM to allow for non-relational backends. In his last update he stated that they have a working MongoDB backend:

> Since this is about the halfway point
>   of GSOC I'll give a general overview:
>   we have a working MongoDB backend,
>   with many implemented features, and a
>   set of changes to Django itself (that
>   don't break anything else of course)
>   that enable this.

http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/36ed23d7b32ff0fd?pli=1

So if you want to use MongoDB with the Django ORM you can switch to django-norel and use django-mongodb-engine or you can wait for Alex's work to be merged into the trunk.

Answer (score 2):

We use [django-mongodb-engine](http://django-mongodb.org/) in production and we haven't face any performance issues. It is well known that using django-mongodb-engine means that you'll be tight to the django ORM, checks, fields and so on. But, you're also able to execute [raw queries](http://django-mongodb.org/reference/lowerlevel.html) when you simply don't care about django ORM.

django-mongodb-engine started taking some ideas from opensource projects (mongodbengine is one of those)

P.S: One of the things I like more about django-mongodb is the easy integration with django because it allow you to simply switch the DB when you need it (Unless you're using "non-standard fields")

P.S2: I'll open a issue requesting some benchmarks

**Update:** The [issue](https://github.com/django-mongodb-engine/mongodb-engine/issues/62) link